# Como fazer uma concatenação de strings com valores de um banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Quero concatenar valores de registros diferentes, como por exemplo, tenho a tabela abaixo:

| id | valor |

---

| 1 | valor1 |

| 2 | valor2 |

| 3 | valor3 |

---

Para mostrar o seguinte resultado: valor1, valor2, valor3

Estou usando PHP + MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta usar a função [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) do MySQL.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(campo SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM tabela;
```